# How do I make sure my computer doesn't reset without asking me first?

Tags: windows-7, reboot, default-settings

I am perfectly happy with my computer letting me know when there are updates that need to be installed and resetting is necessary.  I want it to continue doing that.

I do *not*, however, want it to do so by informing me that if I don't stop it from restarting in the next X minutes it will do so automatically, so that if I happen to be away from the computer when the 10 minute warning pops up, I lose any unsaved work.  I want restarting to be an opt-in feature, not an opt-out feature.  My computer should never restart without me approving it.

Is there a way to change my Microsoft Windows 7 settings to that it does not restart without my approval?

(I don't know the tags here so well.  Please re-tag as appropriate.)

Comment: You just go to the Windows Update settings and set it to not automatically install.  Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I may be mistaken about this, but I thought that not all updates require rebooting.  I want it to still install those updates without rebooting. (Plus I didn't realize it was that simple.)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks - the accepted answer there was exactly what I was looking for.